# Cast nullable bool to bool

Tags: c#

I have an object AlternateName.IsMaidenName

I want to cast that to a checkbox - IsMaidenName

It wont let me cast that as it says Cannot convert source type nullable to target type bool.

I've had this issue in other spots within our application but I wanted to throw it out there for a better way to handle these issues.

```
IsMaidenNameChecked = AlternateName.IsMaidenName;
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

It is quite logical that you cannot cast a nullable bool to a bool, since, what value should the bool have, when the nullable contains null ?

What I would do, is this:

```
IsMaidenNameChecked = AlternateName.IsMaidenName ?? false;
```

Comment: this is nice. i like this even better :-)

Comment: I intially used the thread below (GetValueOrDefault(); ) but this one seems a bit better...both worked though..thanks for the help

Answer (score 18):

```
IsMaidenName.Checked = AlternateName.IsMaidenName.GetValueOrDefault();
```

See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/72cec0e0.aspx

Comment: With the added caveat that the default value for `bool` in .NET is `false`  - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/83fhsxwc.aspx

Comment: Note that there's an [overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3d6d4f1d(v=vs.110).aspx) -- you can say `GetValueOrDefault(true)`, that is, specify the default value to return in case of null.  So you're not restricted to returning `false`.

Answer (score 5):

You probably want to do something like:

```
 IsMaidenNameChecked = AlternateName.IsMaidenName.GetValueOrDefault ();
```

See [Nullable.GetValueOrDefault ()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/72cec0e0.aspx), or you can use the overload that includes an explicit default.

Answer (score 1):

Checkboxes and `Nullable<bool>` both have three states: "true", "false", and "missing".

But you're trying to store the value in an intermediate `bool` variable which has no way to handle "missing".

Try changing your `bool` variable to also be `bool?`.