# Converting Nullable<bool> to bool

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I got this compiler error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'bool?' to 'bool'. An explicit
> conversion exists (are you missing a cast?).

for the following code:

```
 xEnable = was.xEnable;
```

`xEnable` is a nullable column in DB.

Comment: It rather sounds like a normal error to me and not an exception.
You should read: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384091.aspx or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5031519/cast-nullable-bool-to-bool or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6075726/how-to-convert-bool-to-bool-in-c

Comment: What about the ?? operator ? You don't mention anything about it in your question.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This means that

```
xEnable is of type bool
```

and

```
was.xEnable is of type bool? (ie: nullable bool)
```

do something like

```
xEnable = was.xEnable.HasValue ? was.xEnable.Value : false;
```

where **false** is the default value in case **was.xEnable == null**

**EDIT**
Or if you really want you can user the **??** operator like

```
xEnable = was.xEnable ?? true;
```

or

```
xEnable = was.xEnable ?? false;
```

Answer (score 4):

To actually use `??` as in your title, go

```
xEnable = was.xEnable ?? false;
```

if you want `xEnable` to be `false` if `was.xEnable` is `null`, or

```
xEnable = was.xEnable ?? true;
```

if you want `xEnable` to be `true` if `was.xEnable` is `null`.

Answer (score 2):

For C# 8.0 and later, you can use the `??` operator, as you asked, and do

```
xEnable = was.xEnable ?? false;
```

if you want `false` to be the default value when `was.xEnable` is `null`.

Answer (score 1):

If you know that `was.xEnable` is not null, you can use

```
xEnable = was.xEnable.Value
```

If you want to use a default value when `was.xEnable` is `null`, you can do the following

```
bool defaultValue = false;
xEnable = was.xEnable ?? defaultValue;
```

Comment: A better approach would be to user GetValueOrDefault, unless you want/need another default value than the type default. And I wouldn't rely on 'knowing data is not null', specs and data can change over time.

Comment: Agreed - `GetValueOrDefault` is probably what you'd want to use usually, but the question asked about the ?? operator so that's what I used.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to actually pass a null value to the database? If so:

```
xEnable = was.xEnable.HasValue ? was.xEnable.Value : DBNull.Value;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
bool a = false; 
bool? b = null; 
a = (bool)b;
```

this will raise an exception in case when `b` is `null`.

So possible solutions could be:

- you know that `b` is *never* `null`, so use this pattern (bad)
- make `a` nullable too, by  `bool? a = false`;
- check for `null` on `b`, `a = (b == null)?false:b.Value;`

Hope this helps.

Comment: Or `a = b.HasValue && b.Value`